# Admob Unable to request for new Pin due to disable all option

Tags: admob

Trying to new pin request but unfortunatelry its disable and cannot able to do anything. Even I am not getting error message nor warning from Admob via mail. I have just correct my mail address on saturday and after updating this screen I'll be getting.

Check below image
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also seen in my account.

I resolved it using Adsence.

Please try login using [Adsence](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/)
and you will find option generating new PIN there.

In Adsence follow the menu same you are following in Admob.

Comment: Thanks Butani Vijay! You're right I have generated new Pin and now waiting for that. Really many many thanks for your quick response.

Comment: It will not show any advertising until you verify the PIN, right?

Comment: There is time of 6 month. if you will not verify your pin within 6 month ad will be disable